# Pagination Best Practices Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

So I am developing a rails app, and I am working on paginating the feed.  While I was doing it I wondered if I was doing it the right way because my load times were over 1500ms.  My code was:

```
stories = Story.feed
@stories = Kaminari.paginate_array(stories).page(params[:page]).per(params[:pageSize])
```

I have a few questions about this:

1. Should I be paginating `Story.feed`, or is there some sort of method
   that only returns some the stories I need?
2. Is this load time normal?
3. What are other things I can be doing to optimize this

(Also, Story.feed returns an array of story objects.  The code for that is here:

```
  def self.feed
    rawStories = Story.includes([:likes, :viewers, :user, :storyblocks]).all
    newFeaturedStories = rawStories.where(:featured => true).where(:updated_at.gte => (Date.today - 3)).desc(:created_at).entries
    normalStories = rawStories.not_in(:featured => true, :or => [:updated_at.gte => (Date.today - 3)]).desc(:created_at).entries
    newFeaturedStories.entries.concat(normalStories.entries)
  end
```

I am using mongoid and mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you call `Kaminari.paginate_array` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it causes the whole result set to be fetched from DB and loaded in memory similar to calling `Model.all.to_a`.

To avoid this, I'd first find a way to turn `Story.feed` into a scope, rather than a class method. Superficially they'll seem the same—the differences are subtle but deep. See [Active Record scopes vs class methods](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/).

Next, ditch `paginate_array` in favor of chain Kaminari's `page()` and `per()` scopes.

For example (simplified version of yours):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :featured,    -> { where(featured: true) }
  scope :last_3_days, -> { where(:updated_at.gte => (Date.today - 3)).desc(:created_at) }
  scope :feed,        -> { featured.last_3_days }
```

And then paginate simply by going:

```
Article.feed.per(page_size).page(page)
```

The biggest advantage of this is that Kaminari can chain into the generated SQL inserting the proper `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses thereby reducing the size of the result set returned to only what needs to be displayed, as opposed to returning every matching record.

Comment: This only returns the featured stories from the last 3 days.  The functionality I need is for the top stories to be the featured stories regardless of the date and then below that have the rest of the stories sorted by created_at date

Comment: Like I said, it's a simplified version of yours. The point is to use `per().page()` instead of `concat` and `paginate_array` (fetching every matching record). You'll have to be the one to rewrite your entire compound query as a scope (I'm just assuming it's possible, I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you get all feeds from db in an array and this takes long time.

I suggest you use the `any_of` query [from this great gem](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of).

From there, do:

```
def self.feed_stories
  newFeaturedStories = Story.where(:featured => true).where(:updated_at.gte => (Date.today - 3.days))
  normalStories      = Story.not_in(:featured => true, :or => [:updated_at.gte => (Date.today - 3.days)])
  Story.includes([:likes, :viewers, :user, :storyblocks]).any_of(newFeaturedStories, normalStories).desc(:created_at)
end
```

Then paginate this:

```
selected_stories = Story.feed_stories.per(page_size).page(page)
```

Dont really understand what are your `entries` but get them at this moment.

To sum up: the idea s to make a unique paginated db query.

Comment: I'm getting this error ```undefined method `inject' for #<Story:0x007faf703682e8>```

Answer (score -1):

I think Will Paginate will help you out here -> [mislav/will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).
From there you can simply give your controller action .per_page(20) for example and after 20 objects (you can define the objects, see the wiki) there will be pagination

Comment: He's already using the Kaminari gem, which does the same thing.